# Get the last value by month in dax

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I have a table with registered values every day, I need a dax measure to get only the last value of the las day each month.

[Original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfChS.png)

To see only this

[Needed calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeRSq.png)

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this dax query to create a result table with last value of each month

```
Table = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Sheet1[Date], "last_value", LASTNONBLANK(Sheet1[Amount], 1))
```

See the screenshot with test data for reference:

 **Original table:** 
[image]

**Result table:** 
[image]

Let me know if this is what you are looking for and if this solution works.